# Ngrok: "tunnel not found" with custom domain

Tags: node.js, localhost, ngrok

I paid for a Ngrok plan in order to tunnel to my localhost:3000. I have bought a custom domain myexampledomain.com (not this one) from Hover and reserved the same address as my custom domain on my Ngrok account.

I have added the CNAME provided by Ngrok to my domain records in Hover. At Hover they say everything looks fine regarding propagation.

Still I get "Tunnel [www.myexampledomain.com](http://www.myexampledomain.com) not found" when I try to tunnel with http and "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" error with https. I have tried to email Ngrok support yesterday and heard nothing. Anybody who has resolved this same problem?

Alternatively, I would appreciate tips for having a custom url for my local Node.js website (on Mac). Another tunnel provider that works with custom domains? Not even a tunnel is needed, just a custom address that is visible for testers on my computer instead of localhost:3000. I would not want to touch /etc/hosts file as I'm close to my project deadline and afraid of causing problems to the actual localhost. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue except https. (I have never tried it. I have tried only http.)

What plan did you paid? I thought basic plan is enough for this feature, but it requires pro plan.

If you have pro plan, please check the belows:

1. Whether you created the domain with your custom domain.
2. Whether you run ngrok command with `-hostname` option.

For example, if your subdomain(hostname + custom domain name) is `myhost.myexampledomain.com`, please run the command:

```sh
ngrok http -region=us -hostname=myhost.myexampledomain.com 80
```